# How to Display custom errors JSON Result in WEB.API

Tags: javascript, json, asp.net-web-api, exception

I'M new to `Web.API`. I've the URL

http://localhost:21923/communities/getPost/locationID=1.

If suppose, by mistake i used `location` instead of `locationID`  in the above URL it showing [Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FM1bt.png). Instead of that i need to return the following JSON Result.

```js
{
  "message": "Parameter missmatch",
  "errorCode": 404 (or) something else,
  "Status": false
}
```

How can is show that JSON result instead of that pre-defined error in Web.API?

Comment: You should have a look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/error-handling/exception-handling

Comment: I've gone through that. But, there compiler need to go into action method then it'll check whether that ID is present or not. If not then it throwing error. But, in my case it won't even go in to action method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using Application_Error handler in Global.asax:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/24395wz3.aspx

```
void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  // Code that runs when an unhandled error occurs

  // Get the exception object.
  Exception exc = Server.GetLastError();

  // Handle HTTP errors by sending the JSON (only for Http Error)
  if (exc.GetType() == typeof(HttpException))
  {
    // The Complete Error Handling Example generates
    // some errors using URLs with "NoCatch" in them;
    // ignore these here to simulate what would happen
    // if a global.asax handler were not implemented.
      if (exc.Message.Contains("NoCatch") || exc.Message.Contains("maxUrlLength"))
      return;

    //Return a JSON object
    Response.Write(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new
    {
        "message": "Parameter missmatch",
        "errorCode": "404 (or) something else",
        "Status": false
    })
    );
  }

  // For other kinds of errors give the user some information
  // but stay on the default page
  Response.Write("<h2>Global Page Error</h2>\n");
  Response.Write(
      "<p>" + exc.Message + "</p>\n");
  Response.Write("Return to the <a href='Default.aspx'>" +
      "Default Page</a>\n");

  // Log the exception and notify system operators
  ExceptionUtility.LogException(exc, "DefaultPage");
  ExceptionUtility.NotifySystemOps(exc);

  // Clear the error from the server
  Server.ClearError();
}
```

Comment: Thanks it's working. But, how to get the error code like 404 or 500 or something else in errorCode?

Comment: Cast exc to HttpExeception and use GetHttpCode() method to get the int value of the status code: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpexception.gethttpcode(v=vs.110).aspx


`"errorCode": ((HttpException)exec).GetHttpCode();`